# Why no data received by recvfrom through broadcast IP?

Tags: c, linux, networking

I am playing with the function to receive broadcast messages through this example.

> https://github.com/romen/unp/blob/master/unpv13e/bcast/udpcli01.c
> https://github.com/romen/unp/blob/master/unpv13e/bcast/dgclibcast1.c

The issue I have is that I cannot get any data from the broadcast IP.

```
void dg_cli(FILE* fp, int sockfd, const SA* pservaddr, socklen_t servlen)
{
    int n;
    const int on = 1;
    char sendline[MAXLINE], recvline[MAXLINE + 1];
    socklen_t len;
    struct sockaddr* preply_addr;

    preply_addr = Malloc(servlen);

    Setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &on, sizeof(on));

    Signal(SIGALRM, recvfrom_alarm);

    while (Fgets(sendline, MAXLINE, fp) != NULL) {

        Sendto(sockfd, sendline, strlen(sendline), 0, pservaddr, servlen);

        alarm(5);
        for (;;) {
            len = servlen;
            printf("waiting on recvfrom...\n");
            n = recvfrom(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE, 0, preply_addr, &len);
            printf("return from recvfrom\n");
            if (n < 0) {
                if (errno == EINTR)
                    break; /* waited long enough for replies */
                else
                    err_sys("recvfrom error");
            }
            else {
                recvline[n] = 0; /* null terminate */
                printf("from %s: %s",
                    Sock_ntop_host(preply_addr, len), recvline);
            }
        }
    }
    free(preply_addr);
}
```

Note: I replace all real IP address with some word(i.e. abc, hij etc.)

```
$ ifconfig |grep broadcast
        inet 192.168.abc.55  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.abc.255
        inet 192.168.hij.1   netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.hij.255

$ ./udpcli01 192.168.abc.255
hello
waiting on recvfrom...
recvfrom_alarm: 14
return from recvfrom
errno == EINTR

$ ./udpcli01 192.168.hij.255
hello
waiting on recvfrom...
recvfrom_alarm: 14
return from recvfrom
errno == EINTR

$ ./udpcli01 127.0.0.1
hello
waiting on recvfrom...
recvfrom_alarm: 14
return from recvfrom
errno == EINTR
```

Question> Can someone point to me why I cannot get anything from the broadcast address?

Comment: You start listening after the string was sent; so the sent packet is lost. Use select(), or send from one thread, and receive from another one.  Or start two processes, but only one of them will receive.  When timed out, you should loop back and keep on listening,.

Comment: I tried two processes but still it doesn't work for me.

Comment: did you open your firewall?

Comment: My workstation might have blocked this.